# why I can't create a property dynamically?

Tags: javascript, typescript

I'm new to typescript, just a question on. We know that we can define a property in javascript dynamically as:

```
class Rectangle {
  constructor(height, width) {
    this.height = height;
    this.width = width;
  }
}
```

but we can't do the same thing when use typescript as:

```
class Rectangle {
  constructor(height:number, width:number) {
    this.height = height;   //error 
    this.width = width;     //error 
  }
}
```

I know that if add access identifier such as `pubic` as prefix of parameters in the constructor as:

```
 ...
 constructor(public height:number, public width:number) {...}  //which create declaration automatically
```

will fix the problem, but I am just wondering, isn't that typescript the superset of javascript? so typescript should support all valid javascript syntax as well?

Comment: what you got is NOT a syntax error, it's a type error. So yeah it does support all valid js syntax. Yet, if you don't type annotate your stuff properly, it'll give you type error even when the syntax is right. That what typescript does on top of javascript.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following is the flow of a TS interpretation.

1. All properties, methods are initialized.
2. Then during instantiation, constructor is called and above properties are set with default values.

In your code:

```
class Rectangle {
  constructor(height:number, width:number) {
    this.height = height;   //error 
    this.width = width;     //error 
  }
}
```

There are no properties mentioned and hence you get an error

Comment: @Rajesh  thanks for the answer, but when you says All properties, methods are initialized in step 1, let's take height property for example and the corresponding passing argument valye is 3, does it mean sth like :`this.height` is first set to 0 (default value first)  then constructor set `this.height` to 3?

Comment: @secondimage sort of. What I said about *step 1*, is the fact that classes are initialized at compile time and objects at run time. So when your code is being compiled, TS finds no properties. So when you do `this.<something>`, there is no reference to this property in associated type. Hence error

Answer (score 3):

> It is a strict syntactical superset of JavaScript, and adds optional static typing to the language

Another thing to note is that things like features which are not strongly-typed or similar things won't work in TypeScript, this phenomena is similar to it.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it, but of course you'll fight against the type-checking feature of the language.

```
class Rectangle {
  constructor(height:number, width:number) {
    (this as any).height = height;
    (this as any).width = width;
  }
}

const rt = new Rectangle(100, 200);
console.log((rt as any).width);
```

That is, if you cast to any, you can do everything as you would do in plain JavaScript.

Comment: Using `as any` in TS is a bad convention

Comment: I know, but in practice this is what the user asked.

Comment: As a senior developer / member of community you should not suggest this kind of solutions

Comment: @MarioVernari as more experienced, if OP or anyone is asking a patch, its your responsibility to point it out and suggest the right way. We are here to share knowledge and not do someone's work. By sharing right practices, you'll help readers more than you know

Comment: @Rajesh I don't know why the user asked a similar question, but obviously it sounds as a "nonsense" subject: if you choose TypeScript is because you want to leverage the type-checking, where the plain JS is much shooting at your own feet. IMHO, there are situations where you have no other ways than cast as any, basically when a library offers no mapping facility. I myself would never do that, but I think it's also importanto to know how the things are.